# Using str_replace with smarty variable

Tags: php, smarty

Basically I just want to strip out a part of my smarty variable contents.

```
{foreach from=$_sequences key=k item=v}

{if $v.pri == $smarty.get.cf && $v.type == 'TTS'}

{$v.data}

{/if}

{/foreach}
```

`{$v.data}` will echo out 21,5555555555

I want it to only echo out 5555555555. I tried `str_replace` but couldn't get it working..

```
str_replace('"','',${v.data});//   - doesn't work

str_replace('"','',$v.data);// - doesn't work
```

What would be the best way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a modifier:

```
{$v.data|regex_replace:"/^\d+,/":""}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! That is just what I needed. I will remember this from now on.

Say if $v.data echoed out "test" with the quotes around it. How would you use regex to remove the quotes and just echo out test?

Comment: try this: {$v.data|regex_replace:'/^"\d+,(\d+)"/':"$1"}
I'm not sure how capturing parenthesis is exactly like this in Smarty, but in case it doesn't work you can chain modifiers:
{$v.data|regex_replace:'/^\d+,':""|replace:'"':''}

More on modifiers: http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.modifiers.php

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! I tried the first one, and it still had the "'s. The second one doesn't display any data and is just blank.

Comment: maybe this: {$v.data|regex_replace:"/^\d+,/":""|regex_replace:"/\D/":""}

Comment: Hmmm.. same thing. That is also blank O_o

Answer (score 6):

This is the way str_replace in Smarty works:

```
{"replace_this_text"|str_replace:"I am the new text":$value}
```

General, Smarty's pipe '|' operator use the value before the pipe as the first argument for the called function, which is the search text in case of str_replace.